# Passing back-end data after authentication to be rendered to the screen in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

***Note that you needn't to go through all of the code, I have added them for reference.***

I have a login screen that authenticates the user's details from backend data. I have used a reusable `Auth.jsx` component to initialize and do authentication:

```
    class Auth
    {
        constructor()
        {
            this.authenticated = false;
        }
        login(props)
        {
            this.authenticated = true;
            alert(props);
        }
        logout(cb)
        {
            this.authenticated = false;
        }
        isAuthenticated()
        {
            return this.authenticated;
        }
    
    }

export default new Auth();
```

Here is the code to trigger function in my login for backend verification, **you may ignore the rest of the code and go directly to submit button callback**.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import ErrorCodes from '../constants/ErrorCodes.jsx';
import LoginDetails from '../constants/LoginDetails.jsx';
import Auth from '../security/Auth.jsx';
export default function LoginScreen(props)
{
  const [credentials,setCredentials] = useState({
    email:"",
    password:""
  });
  const [credentialMessage,setcredentialMessage]=useState({
    email:"",
    password:""
  });
  function ErrorChecker()
  {
    let regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if(regex.test(credentials["email"]))
      setcredentialMessage({...credentialMessage, ["email"]: ErrorCodes[0]});
 
    else
      setcredentialMessage({...credentialMessage, ["email"]: ErrorCodes[4]});

  }
  function LoginScreenRenderer(props)
  {
    return <Form.Group key={props.id} autocomplete="off" controlId={props.controlId}>
    <Form.Label>{props.Label}</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type={props.type} placeholder={props.placeholder}
    value={credentials[props.type]} onChange={e=>{
      setCredentials({...credentials, [props.type]: e.target.value});
      ErrorChecker();
      }}
    />
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
      {credentialMessage[props.type]}
      </Form.Text>
  </Form.Group>;
  }
  return(
    <Form className="FormAligner">
    {LoginDetails.map(LoginScreenRenderer)}
    <Button onClick={async(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      const JSONString = credentials;
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/login',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(JSONString)
      }).then(response=>response.json()).then((jsonData)=>{
        if(jsonData["Is_Valid"])
        {
          Auth.login("HelloWorld");
          props.history.push("/login-props-test");
        }
      });
    }}>Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

And here's the code for my private router (for the url: "/login-props-test"):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Auth from '../security/Auth.jsx';


const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component,...rest}) => {
  return(
    <Route {...rest} render ={
      (props)=>{
        alert(props);
        if(Auth.isAuthenticated())
        return <Component{...props} />
        else
        {
          return <Redirect to={
            {
              pathname: "/login",
              state: {
                from: props.location
              }
            }
          }/>
        }

      }
    }/>
  );
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

If the authentication is successful, I want to push my data to another functional component `DisplayScreen.jsx` where I will be rendering all this things. Here's the code for that too:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function DisplayScreen(props)
{
    //const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
    const isLoggedIn = false;
    return(isLoggedIn?<div>
        <h1 class="ErrorPage-Header">Login Unsuccessful</h1>
        <p class="ErrorPage-Body">Seems like there were some issues while loggin you in.
        Maybe try to <a href='/login' className="href-AnchorTag">login again</a> or contact Administrator.</p>
        </div>:<div>
        <div className="row">
        <div className="block">Stats Info</div>
        <div className="block">Welcome to Your Dashboard</div>
        <div className="block">Logo</div>
        </div>
        <div>Toggle Button</div>
        <div className="row">
        <div className="block">Chart-01</div>
        <div className="block">Chart-02</div>
        <div className="block">Chart-03</div>
        </div>
        </div>);
}
```

I want to push data to those props. I have created the routes as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import StarterScreen from './components/screens/StarterScreen.jsx';
import LoginScreen from './components/screens/LoginScreen.jsx';
import RegisterScreen from './components/screens/RegisterScreen.jsx';
import DisplayScreen from './components/screens/DisplayScreen.jsx';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/security/PrivateRoute.jsx';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
  function App(){
    return (
    <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
    <Route component={StarterScreen} exact path="/"></Route>
    <Route component={RegisterScreen} exact path="/register"></Route>
    <Route component={LoginScreen} exact path="/login"></Route>
    <ProtectedRoute component={DisplayScreen} exact path="/login-props-test" />
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
    }

export default App;
```

My major objective is to push those data as props in `DisplayScreen(props)`. I know this maybe a very simple problem, but I am new to React so any kind of help would be really appreciated. Note that I would be fetching the API data in submit button of login function the way I fetched credential validation data. I just want to know what exactly do I do next after fetching that data to send them as props to `DisplayScreen`.

For example the code will look something like this:

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/login',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
          'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(JSONString)
      }).then(response=>response.json()).then((jsonData)=>{
        if(jsonData["Is_Valid"])
        {
          const BackendData = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/fetch',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
              'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(BackendData)
          }).then(response=>response.json()).then((jsonBackend)=>{
            //properties_to_pass = jsonBackend
            //Auth.login(properties_to_pass);
            props.history.push("/login-props-test");
          });
          
        }
      });
```

Kindly help me with achieving the same. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out with the following:

1. Passing JSONData in login function:

   Auth.login(jsonBackend);
2. Collecting that data in `Auth.jsx` as props property:

   login(props)
   {
   this.authenticated = true;
   this.jsonData = props;
   }
3. Returning this instead of this.authenticated and collecting it @ `privateroute.jsx`:

> ```
> const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component,...rest}) => {
>   return(
>     <Route {...rest} render ={
>       (props)=>{
>         if(Auth.isAuthenticated().authenticated)
>         return <Component{...Auth.isAuthenticated().jsonData} />
>         else
>         {
>           return <Redirect to={
>             {
>               pathname: "/login",
>               state: {
>                 from: props.location
>               }
>             }
>           }/>
>         }
>
>       }
>     }/>
>   );
> }
>
> export default ProtectedRoute;
> ```

And then picking it up at my `displayscreen.jsx`. Hope this may help someone searching it in future.